# Need a sortable JavaScript table which can handle real-time updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, widget, real-time

I need a sortable table or grid widget in JavaScript which can handle real-time updates.  I will be updating rows within the table via updates from Comet and preferably don't want a widget that requires me to redraw the whole table on each update or hogs the CPU when updating.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/). It has configurable data adapters that can work from local data (XML, array, JSON, etc.), or remote.

There are [many grid examples](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html#sample-2), but [this one](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html) might meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but I did come across jqGrid a few days ago.  Has loads of examples.

[Main Site](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
[Examples](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

Dojo's [Dojox Grid](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid) purportedly supports this feature when used with a [QueryReadStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/data/QueryReadStore) as its backend.

Unfortunately, I do not have a working example of this.